# Confused about passing data controller to viewmodel to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I haven't done any MVC for 2 years now so I think I am just very rusty right now.  I use the below code to display a simple list of data from my DB on my page but I get the error

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Models.UsersViewModel' because '.Models.UsersViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I'm sure I just missed something very dumb but as I said, I'm just dipping my foot back into the pond.

Thx for any insight.

Business.User

```
    public Decimal USER_ID { get; set; }
    public String USERNAME { get; set; }
    public String SURNAME { get; set; }
    public String GIVENNAME { get; set; }

    public static List<User> GetList()
    {
        Entities ctx = new Entities();

        List<User> a = (from x in ctx.TABLE1
                        select new User()
                        {
                            USER_ID = x.USER_ID,
                            USERNAME = x.USERNAME,
                            SURNAME = x.SURNAME,
                            GIVENNAME = x.GIVENNAME
                        }).OrderBy(o => o.SURNAME).ToList();
        return a;
    }
```

Controller

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.EnvPath = CurrentENV;

        var usersViewModel = new UsersViewModel();
        usersViewModel._Users = Business.User.GetList();

        return View(usersViewModel);
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
    public List<Business.User> _Users { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
    @model ProactiveDisclosure.Models.UsersViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {

    }

    </table>
```

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model._Users) {`

Comment: Should't it be Model._Users?

Comment: That's what i thought as well, however the foreach says 'IEnumerable<UsersViewModel>' does not contain a definition for '_Users' and no extension method '_Users' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<UsersViewModel>' when i add Model._Users

Answer (score 1):

`UsersViewModel` **contains** a list of `Business.User`. It is not a list of `Business.User` itself.

Change the iteration to `@foreach(var user in Model._Users)`

Comment: That's what i thought as well, however the foreach says 'IEnumerable<UsersViewModel>' does not contain a definition for '_Users' and no extension method '_Users' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<UsersViewModel>' when i add Model._Users

Comment: Can you post the actual code that you're now using?

Answer (score 0):

Well, strangely,it started working when i closed down my Index.cshtml and re-opened with Model._Users